# Entity Framework Core отправляет запрос на адреса Microsoft при обращении к библиотеке

Tags: c#, база-данных, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Моя программа (`C#`, `WinForms`, `Visual Studio`) использует `Entity Framework Core` для работы с `Office Access`. Поставщиком базы данных является [Jet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFrameworkCore.Jet/). Контекст сгенерирован командой `Scaffold-DbContext`.

Когда во время работы программы вызываются команды контекста `Add()`, `Update()`, `Remove()`, `SaveChanges()` - от программы идет исходящий запрос (ловит брандмауэр антивируса). Запрос на адрес `52.109.*.*`. К примеру, `52.109.124.23`. Согласно [Whois](https://whois.ru/52.109.124.23) адрес принадлежит `Microsoft`.

Подобная активность привлекает антивирус и сказывается на работе программы.

Хотелось бы узнать цель данного запроса и способ отключения. Я знаю, что можно внести в исключения брандмауэра. Но непонятные запросы от этого не пропадут.

Comment: Может быть, включена телеметрия .net core? Отключается командой `setx DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT 1`

Comment: @kmv Выполнил команду. Запрос все равно появляется.